# Given an abstract open book obtaining a 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $\Sigma_{\phi}$ be the mapping torus of $\phi$, i.e., $\Sigma \times [0,1] / \sim$ where $(\phi(x),0) \sim (x,1)$ for all $x \in \Sigma$. Also let

$$M_{\phi} = \Sigma_{\phi} \cup_{\psi} (\coprod_{|\partial\Sigma|} S^1 \times D^2)$$

where $|\partial\Sigma|$ is the number of boundary components of $\Sigma$. For each boundary component $l$ of $\Sigma$, the map $\psi: \partial(S^1 \times D^2) \rightarrow l \times S^1$ is defined to be unique (up to isotopy) diffeomorphism that takes $S^1 \times \{p\}$ to $l$ where $p \in \partial D^2$, and $\{q\} \times \partial D^2$ to $(\{ q'\} \times [0,1] / \sim) = S^1$ where $q \in S^1$ and $q' \in \partial \Sigma$.

Now suppose $\Sigma$ is a surface of genus $g$ with $n$ boundary components and $\phi$ is the identity map on $\Sigma$. What I want to prove is that $M_{\phi} = \#_{2g+n-1} S^1 \times S^2$.

---

I could not prove the assertion for the general case. But for $g=1, n=0$ case I found the following.

Since $M_{\phi} = \Sigma_{\phi} \cup_{\psi} (\coprod_{|\partial\Sigma|} S^1 \times D^2)$ and $n=0$, for this case we have $M_{\phi} = \Sigma_{\phi}$. Then $\Sigma_{\phi} = \Sigma \times [0,1] / \sim = S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$. But the question suggests the answer $\#_{2g+n-1} S^1 \times S^2$, that is, in our case, $S^1 \times S^2$.

**Questions:** Is the specific case solution correct? Is the assertion of the question correct (general case)?

---

The question and the above definitions are from *[Lectures on open book decompositions and contact structures](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.SG/0409402)* by [John Etnyre](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~etnyre/).